# User Authentication failed in angularFire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angularfire5

```
//Login component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent  {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth , public router: Router) { }
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then((sucess) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/option']);
  });
}
```

angularFire2 version --5.0.0-rc.10
firebase version --4.13.1

I have imported the AngularFireAuthModule and AngularFireModule in my  app.module.ts and enabled google authentication in firebase console but am still getting an error message as-[this is the error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4CZc.png)
Please Help !!

Comment: Did you enable google login in Authentication settings?

Comment: yes i had enabled it

Comment: cannot comment by seeing this..its better to share in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

did you provided the correct Config for FireBase? With all you auth domain and api keys?

See step 4: [AngularFire2 installation Guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)

Please don't forget to not post the config here, or to change your values as it contains Secret keys.

Comment: yes i did provide the correct config for firebase along with auth domain and api key

Comment: are you using a button with a submit behavior? if so can you try to remove the submit or if you use it inside of a form remove the form tag swell